# How to manage onItemClickListener using ListActivity

Tags: android, listview

I've got some idea in my mind but I don't how to get started.

There is a one listview, firstly listadapter contains for example names of coubtries, then in onItemClickListener:

- when I tap some country, listadapter will be changed and on list will show cities connected with chosen country
- when I press back arrow (android button) listadapter should change and I'll see countries as at beginning
- when I tap some cities I'll go to other activity

Is it wise and comfortable to make this task in mentioned way?

--

the question is how to switch the one listview onitemclicklistener for the second one, and make working back arrow?

Answer (score 0):

I would have two different `ListView`s, one for countries and one for cities.  The country `ListView` would be static (its content unchanging, not Java `static`).  The cities ListView would change as countries were selected, and would only be populated once a country was chosen.

Answer (score 0):

What about two different ListView activities, where the country selected in the first one was passed into the 2nd one that did some database lookup or whatever and showed the cities in the selected country?

Comment: Ok, I have two different Listactivietes but how to switch to the second one in first Listviewactivity when item is clicked.

Comment: Create an `Intent` for your second activity, add the country code/ID or whatever as an extra and call `startActivityForResult()`.  In the second activity call `getIntent()` to get the country code from the first activity, and populate your list view based on whatever logic you need.